# How to check/inspect value that I receive from ui.R?

Tags: r, shiny

How can I check/inspect the **value** from the input from `ui.R` that has been passed into in `server.R`?

ui.R,

```
dateInput(inputId =  "date_from", 
                label = "Select time period:", 
                value = "2014-09-02", 
                format = "dd-mm-yyyy"),

      dateInput(inputId =  "date_to", 
                label = "To:", 
                value = "2015-02-29", 
                format = "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

server.R,

```
# Connect to the sqlite file.
DB <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "data/db.sqlite")

# Period.
date_from = input$date_from 
date_to = input$date_to

data = dbGetQuery(DB, paste("SELECT * FROM datatable 
                  WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '", date_from,"' 
                  AND '", date_to,"'"))

hist(data$humidity, col = "blue")
```

I don't know how to check the **value** that I get from `ui.R`, but this is what I should get, for instance,

```
2014-09-09 (date_from)
2014-10-09 (date_to)
```

I get this error for the code I have above,

```
Error in hist.default(data$humidity, col = "blue") : 
  invalid number of 'breaks'
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

By using `textOutput`, I get strange values from the `dateInput`, such as `16317` for `04-09-2014` - what does it mean? how can I convert it into `2014-09-04` (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Comment: Use `textOutput` to see the values for `input$date_from` and `input$date_to`. See this example for sliders, but idea is the same: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/sliders.html

Comment: thanks. still don't get it. `textOutput` is not in use in the example you suggest...

Comment: you can use validate to build your test cases 

http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html

Comment: Got it. I get strange values from the `dateInput`, such as `16317` for `04-09-2014` - what does it mean? how can I convert it into `2014-09-04` (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Comment: Also when querying from databases I find it easier to use regular expression to sub into the fields that I need (Date, time, variables, etc.) in the query string, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934967/r-shiny-date-range-input-to-sql-query/28947097#28947097