# SQL Query Error when selecting separate columns

Tags: sql, r, shiny

I do not understand the error which appears in my SQL Query. If i choose in SQL 
`Select *` -> it is working fine and i do get the table,
however if i select **any** of the column/s it is giving me an Error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PROBE", value =
>   structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor")) :
>   replacement has 0 rows, data has 1427

Here is my SQL code:

```
if(input$filter == 1){
        sqlOutput <- reactive({
          sqlInput <- paste("select * from DWH.PROBE where DWH.PROBE.Nr =",paste0("'",d(),"'"), "And DWH.PROBE.AB BETWEEN",input$abmfrom, "AND",input$abmto,"ORDER BY Datum asc")
          print(sqlInput)
          dbGetQuery(con$cc, sqlInput)
        })
      }else{
        sqlOutput <- reactive({
          sqlInput <-  paste("select * from DWH.PROBE where DWH.PROBE.S BETWEEN",d2(), "AND",input$sgehalt2, "And DWH.PROBE.AB BETWEEN",input$abmfrom2, "AND",input$abmto2,"ORDER BY Datum asc")
          dbGetQuery(con$cc, sqlInput)
        })}
```

And if i just add to those SQL Queries

```
select DWH.PROBE.S, DWH.PROBE.AB.. from DWH.PROBE
```

Then it comes above mentioned Error.

Additionally i need to say if i will use this SQL Query in a simple code:

```
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, paste("select DWH.PROBE.AB, DWH.PROBE.S from DWH.PROBE where DWH.PROBE.Nr = '50' And DWH.PROBE.AB BETWEEN 40 AND 50 ORDER BY Datum asc"))
data <- fetch(rs)
```

It is giving me the results...

Any ideas?

[EDIT *as my question is not a duplicate]

The question posted here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048072/how-to-pass-input-variable-to-sql-statement-in-r-shiny](http://about%20how%20to%20pass%20input%20variable%20to%20sql) actually has nothing to do with my topic. As we can see the error in this post:

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : Operation not
>   allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something
>   that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

**I do not have a problems with passing input variable to sql statement and additionally if you can see in my SQL: The Query is in reactive context!:**

```
sqlOutput <- reactive({...
```

The solution for above question was:

**to put SQL Query in reactive context** which is not a thing in my case

**[EDIT 2]** -> bits related to `sqlOutput()`

Here is a bit of code related to `sqlOutput()` which i am using in my Shiny App (at the moment this is the only bit because i am stuck with SQL Query)

```
output$tabelle <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data <- sqlOutput()
    data$PROBE <- as.factor(as.character(data$PROBE))
    data
    }, rownames=TRUE, filter="top", class = 'cell-border stripe', 
                      options = list(pageLength = 100, lengthMenu=c(100,200,500), columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"),list(bSortable = FALSE, targets = "_all"))))
```

Thanks

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass input variable to SQL statement in R shiny?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048072/how-to-pass-input-variable-to-sql-statement-in-r-shiny)

Comment: Its is not duplicate @Pork Chop if you have noticed my SQL Query is in reactive context* so that is not the problem

Comment: @zx8754 I am not creating any new columns, neither subsetting it. I just want to get the specific columns from databank (in the databank there are 50 columns, i need just 10 of them)

Comment: as.factor(as.character... Why?

Comment: because this column is a numeric column, i need to change it to the factor (direct change to factor is giving NA's)

Answer (score 0):

Error doesn't relate to SQL statements, however, try changing your code to below:

```
sqlOutput <- reactive({
  if(input$filter == 1){
    sqlInput <- paste("select * from DWH.PROBE where DWH.PROBE.Nr =",paste0("'",d(),"'"), "And DWH.PROBE.AB BETWEEN",input$abmfrom, "AND",input$abmto,"ORDER BY Datum asc")
  } else {
    sqlInput <- paste("select * from DWH.PROBE where DWH.PROBE.S BETWEEN",d2(), "AND",input$sgehalt2, "And DWH.PROBE.AB BETWEEN",input$abmfrom2, "AND",input$abmto2,"ORDER BY Datum asc")
  }
  dbGetQuery(con$cc, sqlInput)
})
```

Comment: if the problem is not in SQL , then where possibly it can be, as an easy SQL Query which i posted at the end, gives the desired Table...

Comment: @Malvina_a we cannot really tell, add your full code (at least bits where it is related to this SQL output)

Comment: I have just edited my question and i pasted there bit of my code where `sqlOutput()` is used