# Passing a SQL input date range into a query in SHINY

Tags: sql-server, r, shiny, rodbc, shinydashboard

I'm learning to use Shiny and shiny dashboard and working with a sql database SQL-SERVER where I'd like to pull the data straight from the database. Essentially the idea is to merge to columns in a table that have a start spot and a stop spot for a date range, tabulate them and then diagram them.

I found the following posting on how to pass sql input statements into shiny:
[How to pass input variable to SQL statement in R shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048072/how-to-pass-input-variable-to-sql-statement-in-r-shiny)

Unfortunately when I try and apply this I get an error 'subscript is out of bounds; it looks like the query isn't being pulled in. I've tested it separately and was able to pull the data and run through each step without issue. I am using the RODBC package which I wonder if this is the issue. Below is my code:

```
         library(stringr)
        library(RODBC)
          library(circlize)
         library(shinydashboard)
         library(shiny)

                ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
                dashboardHeader(title = "sample"),
                dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                dashboardBody(
                  # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
                  fluidRow(
                    box(title = "Route Volume", background = "green", solidHeader = TRUE,
                        plotOutput(outputId= 'plot2'))),
                    fluidRow( 
                      box(background= "green", dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date Range"),start = '2016-06-01',
                                                              end = '2016-06-05')), width = 4

                      ))))

              server <- function(input, output) {
            database = odbcConnect("datatbase")
            output$plot2 = renderPlot({

            d = paste0("SELECT 
               top 30
           convert(char(10),datetime,121) as date, 
           cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
           + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3)) as combo,
           count(cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
           + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3))) as volume
           FROM
           trips
           WHERE datetime >= ",input$dates[1]," AND
           datetime < ",input$dates[2],"
           GROUP BY
           cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
           + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3)),
           convert(char(10),datetime,121);")

        sql = sqlQuery(database, d)

           sql = data.frame(sql, do.call(rbind, str_split(sql$combo, ',')))
       colnames(sql)[colnames(sql)=="X1"] <- "From"
         colnames(sql)[colnames(sql)=="X2"] <- "To"
         sql = sql[,c(4,5,3)]
         sql = sql[order(sql$volume, decreasing = T),]
          chordDiagram(sql)
          circos.clear()

          })

          }


          shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm sure this is some silly mistake, a missing quotation mark or a misunderstanding on my part of how to apply these techniques. Appreciate the help!!

```
                ##adding edits by Dean to test



              database = odbcConnect("database")
             output$plot2 = renderPlot({
              if(input$dates[1]!= "") {
               d = paste0("SELECT 
            top 30
          convert(char(10),datetime,121) as date, 
          cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
          + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3)) as combo,
          count(cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
          + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3))) as volume
          FROM
           trips
           WHERE 
           datetime >= ",input$dates[1]," AND
           datetime < ",input$dates[2],"
           GROUP BY
          cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
          + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3)),
           convert(char(10),datetime,121);")
         sql = sqlQuery(database, d) 

        #i assumed the if statement ended here so I put the 
        #bracket below 
           sql = data.frame(sql, do.call(rbind, str_split(sql$combo, ',')))
       colnames(sql)[colnames(sql)=="X1"] <- "From"
         colnames(sql)[colnames(sql)=="X2"] <- "To"
         sql = sql[,c(4,5,3)]
         sql = sql[order(sql$volume, decreasing = T),]
          chordDiagram(sql)
          circos.clear() 

}
    })

   }
```

Putting up edits to the server following suggestions by NJburgo 
                   ##################################NJburgo  suggestion################
                   #I get the error: Do not know how to convert input$dates to  class date

```
                       database = odbcConnect("database")
                           output$plot2 = renderPlot({
                           dates = as.Date(input$dates)
                           d = paste0("SELECT 
                       top 30
                      convert(char(10),datetime,121) as date, 
                     cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
                      + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3)) as combo,
                       count(cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
                     + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3))) as volume  
                     FROM
                    trips
                      WHERE 
                      datetime >= {d '",input$dates[1],"'} AND
                       datetime < {d '",input$dates[2],"'}
                        GROUP BY
                      cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
                       + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3)),
                        convert(char(10),datetime,121);")
                   sql = sqlQuery(database, d) 


                   sql = data.frame(sql, do.call(rbind, str_split(sql$combo, ',')))
                 colnames(sql)[colnames(sql)=="X1"] <- "From"
                 colnames(sql)[colnames(sql)=="X2"] <- "To"
                 sql = sql[,c(4,5,3)]
                 sql = sql[order(sql$volume, decreasing = T),]
               chordDiagram(sql)
                   circos.clear() 

               })

             }
```

Comment: Using string concatenation to construct a SQL query is a bug in itself. Unexpected conversions of date and number parameters are just one of the problems that it can cause. Use proper [parameterized queries](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html) to avoid all quoting, format and security issues

Comment: One guess is that shiny is running the sql before the `input$dates` has values in it.  I would put `print(input$dates[1])` and `print(input$dates[2])` before the sql query happens and then run the app.  This assumes you're running from Rstudio so that you can see what it prints in the Rstudio window.

Comment: Hey Dean. I tried printing the input$dates but it made no difference. Im sure the issue is here because when dates are hardcoded the data pulls without issue.

Comment: I didn't expect the printing to make a difference.  It's just a debugging step.  Did it print the dates or did it print blanks?

Comment: Gotcha. It didn't print anything. Just blanks, it's as if shiny isn't interpreting input$dates to put into the SQL query which is why the query is blank too

Comment: if it printed blanks that means shiny is triggering your `renderPlot` before it has its starting values.  Try wrapping everything just inside of your `renderPlot` block with an `if(input$dates[1]!="")`

Comment: This makes sense, I'm not quite sure exactly how you mean so I added the edited server part to the code on the top of the question so you can check; when I try and do it this way it doesn't work. Appreciate the help on this really!

Comment: You've got too many end braces in that update.  Assuming your actual code doesn't have the extra braces, try hard coding some dates in and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah, I just edited the script and pulled out the brackets. When I run it with the if statement I still get nothing, essentially sql the query I'm pulling doesn't even appear, it's blank. When I hard code the dates with the if statement i still get nothing; I do however get the following error: **Error in charToDate: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.**.  When I remove the if statement and hard code dates, the app runs fine. It's as if as soon as I replace  datetime >= '2016-01-01' with datetime >= '",input$dates[1],"' etc. the query ceases to function.

Comment: Hmm I'm a bit stumped.  One thing that looks different but don't really know if it'll make a difference is that you have `server <- function(input, output)` and I use `server <- function(input, output, session)`.  I don't know if that makes a difference but give it a shot.  The problem is that your `input$dates` seems to always be empty

Comment: @LoF10 see the comment string after my answer, SQL wont understand the default format for a R date you seem to hae tried.

Answer (score 0):

##########################figured out answer. It required a combination of both suggestions from all of you making sure date printed and was converted as well. Thank you all!Below is working code

```
                server <- function(input, output) {

             output$plot2 = renderPlot({
           database = odbcConnect("database")
              start_date = print(input$dates[1])
              end_date = print(input$dates[2])
              my_query="SELECT 
              top 30
                        convert(char(10),datetime,121) as date, 
                         cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
                        + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3)) as combo,
                           count(cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
                           + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3))) as volume  
                          FROM
                          trips
                              WHERE 
                           datetime >= DATE1 AND
                           datetime < DATE2
                            GROUP BY
                             cast(start_destination as varchar(3)) 
                           + (',') + cast(final_destination as varchar(3)),
                             convert(char(10),datetime,121);"

                my_query <- sub("DATE1",as.Date(start_date),my_query);
              my_query <- sub("DATE2",as.Date(end_date),my_query)
             sql = sqlQuery(database, paste(my_query))
            sql = data.frame(sql, do.call(rbind, str_split(sql$combo, ',')))
           colnames(sql)[colnames(sql)=="X1"] <- "From"
           colnames(sql)[colnames(sql)=="X2"] <- "To"
           sql = sql[,c(4,5,3)]
            sql = sql[order(sql$volume, decreasing = T),]
            chordDiagram(sql)
             circos.clear()
               })


             }


             shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this as R thing, more likely SQL, especially if your query works with ordinary dates outside of Shiny (hint: test this, report back!).

For date comparison in SQL have always had to convert the date as so:

```
...WHERE col_name >= {d '2016-08-04'}...
```

So you have to format the date in R. The simplest way to do this is with format:

```
format(Sys.Date(), "{d '%Y-%m-%d'}")
```

Comment: You *don't* have to convert dates if you avoid string concatenation and use parameterized queries. If you *have* to use them, the unambiguous date format is the unseparated format, ie `20160804`. In any case, it's far easier and safer to use RODBCext which supports [parameterized queries](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html)

Comment: thanks for the tips guys. Panagiotos, I think parameterized queries are definitely where I will need to move after this, but I'm not sure that's the issue here. The query runs fine as is outside of shiny, it just stops inside of shiny. I went ahead and tried your solution NJBurgo pulling with this: WHERE col_name >= {d '",input$dates[1],"'} so that the data is converted to date format and still had not success (this did work outside of shiny though). I did notice  that when I hard code dates into the query works fine. So I think the issue is with input$dates. not sure where. Any ideas?

Comment: @LoF10, in shiny the input from a selectDate is a string, and needs to be converted. Use `date <- as.Date(input$date)` to get a date conversion. Then you can format either using the solution I posted, or formatting it like @panagiotis-kanavos suggested `format(date, '%Y%m%d')`.

Comment: Hey NJburgo, thanks for the update, so I went ahead and gave it a shot. Didn't work but it might be the way I set it up. I added the edits to the post above if you could take a quick look. I wasn't sure if I was supposed to convert both dates[1] and dates[2] or just 'dates'. Either way I got the error "Do not know how to convert input$dates to class Date".

Comment: I did also try dates = format(input$dates, '%Y%m%d') which got me the error: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors